Tailor gaze data by negative transition time
I work with gaze data (here, aoi_C_aoi giving gaze fixations and aoi_C_dur giving the durations of these gaze fixations) during questions (Utterance) in conversation. The issue I am grappling with is how to tailor the gaze data if the response to the question comes before the Utteranceis finished, in which case the Trans_new value (giving the time between question and answer) is negative:
df
  Sequ  Utterance Trans_new     aoi_C_aoi            aoi_C_dur
1   55  where...?      -125 B, *, A, *, B 59, 110, 72, 50, 100
2   77 what's...?      -333          *, A             299, 401

I'm approaching the issue by pivoting longer and separating all gaze data into rows:
df %>% 
  
  # pivot longer:
  pivot_longer(matches("aoi"),
               names_to = c("Gaze_by", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "([ABC])_(.+)") %>%
  # rename more explicitly:
  rename(Gaze_to = aoi) %>%
  # trim whitespace:
  mutate(Gaze_to = trimws(Gaze_to)) %>%
  
  # separate individual data points into rows:
  separate_rows(c(Gaze_to, dur), sep = ", ", convert = TRUE)

But from here, I do not know how to proceed. The desired output is this:
   Sequ Utterance  Trans_new Gaze_by Gaze_to   dur
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <int>
1    55 where...?       -125 C       B          59
2    55 where...?       -125 C       *         110
3    55 where...?       -125 C       A          72
4    55 where...?       -125 C       *          25     # 150 - 125 = 25
#5    55 where...?       -125 C       B         100    # removed as 100 < abs(-125)
6    77 what's...?      -333 C       *         299
7    77 what's...?      -333 C       A         68      # 401 - 333 = 68

Reproducible data:
df <- data.frame(
  Sequ = c(55,77),
  Utterance = c("where...?", "what's...?"),
  Trans_new = c(-125, -333),
  aoi_C_aoi = c("B, *, A, *, B", "*, A"),       
  aoi_C_dur = c("59, 110, 72, 50, 100", "299, 401")
)

Any help findinga tidyverse solution is greatly appreciated.

Here's my own solution. The main 'trick' is to compute cumulative durations from bottom to top so we can see which gazes fall into the transition phase and much they do:
df %>% 
  
  # pivot longer:
  pivot_longer(matches("aoi"),
               names_to = c("Gaze_by", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "([ABC])_(.+)") %>%
  # rename for clarity:
  rename(Gaze_to = aoi) %>%
  # trim whitespace:
  mutate(Gaze_to = trimws(Gaze_to)) %>%
  
  # separate individual data points into rows:
  separate_rows(c(Gaze_to, dur), sep = ", ", convert = TRUE) %>%
  
  group_by(Sequ, Gaze_by) %>%
  mutate(
    # compute cumulative duration from bottom up:
    cumdur_1 = rev(cumsum(rev(dur))),
    # add transition time to cumulative duration (works for negative and positive transitions!):
    dur_1 = cumdur_1 + Trans_new,
         ) %>%
  
  # remove rows with negative `dur_1` values (where gazes fall within the negative transition time):
  filter(dur_1 >= 0) %>%
  
  # determine adjusted gaze durations:
                   # if `dur_1` value IS `last(dur_1)`, take that value, else take value from `dur`:
  mutate(dur_adj = ifelse(dur_1 == last(dur_1), dur_1, dur)) %>%
  ungroup()

